# getting prometheus metrics from pdns

Tags: powerdns, prometheus

Running pdns v4.7.0-0.alpha0.master. Have enabled web server and can see ports 8081, 8081 and 8082 (from localhost login). When I try to get /metrics from there (via curl) I get either "connection refused" or "Not found".

Anyone had success with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having the same issue but worked out the problem so sharing here!

If you turned on the webserver in `pdns.conf` by **just** using `api=yes`, it **just** enables the API - and not the rest of the webserver's advantages!

So add `webserver=yes` to your `pdns.conf` file and reload PowerDNS. Then your metrics will come through wonderfully ✨